# macOS 13.4 and ChromeOS Flex USB

Tags: macos, usb, google-chrome, apfs, parallels-desktop

I'm trying to create a Chrome OS Flex USB install drive, to install it via Parallels, on macOS 13.4 (2019 i9 MBP).

I'm able to create it both via the Chrome browser extension, and the terminal `sudo dd if=chromeos.bin of=/dev/disk2 bs=4M status=progress` method... but after both methods, it shows the same wya in Disk Utility, however it's not readable in macOS, so Parallels cannot install *from it* -- there's no way to pick it as the USB drive source, or open the .bin image.

Am I missing something simple?

I cannot find this as a known issue, and there are instructions on how to do this with a Mac.. here's what I used:

https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11552529?hl=en

https://www.parallels.com/blogs/run-chrome-os-flex-in-parallels-desktop-for-mac/

I tried using the USB band new, and again formatted to APFS first -- but both create the same thing when creating the ChromeOS Flex USB drive, so I don't think the starting point matters.. but here's the drive:

https://www.westerndigital.com/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-cruzer-glide-usb-2-0#SDCZ60-032G-B35

The latest ChromeOS Flex .bin is here: https://dl.google.com/chromeos-flex/images/latest.bin.zip

Additional info I've found already: https://www.reddit.com/r/ChromeOSFlex/comments/swl5q9/chromeos_flex_links/

```
➜  ~ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         4.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +4.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            9.1 GB     disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 9.1 GB     disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     2.2 TB     disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume Preboot                 2.0 GB     disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *31.4 GB    disk2
   1: FE3A2A5D-4F32-41A7-B725-ACCC3285A309               16.8 MB    disk2s2
   2: FE3A2A5D-4F32-41A7-B725-ACCC3285A309               16.8 MB    disk2s4
                    (free space)                         136.3 MB   -
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         16.8 MB    disk2s8
   4:                        EFI EFI-SYSTEM              67.1 MB    disk2s12
   5: 3CB8E202-3B7E-47DD-8A3C-7FF2A13CFCEC               2.1 MB     disk2s5
   6: 3CB8E202-3B7E-47DD-8A3C-7FF2A13CFCEC               2.5 GB     disk2s3
   7:           Linux Filesystem                         4.3 GB     disk2s1
```

[image]

Comment: I know in VirtualBox, you just create a USB filter that automatically passes the USB device directly to the VM.  macOS doesn't read the disk at all.  I would imagine that Parallels has something similar.

Comment: Yea, I see now that macOS just will not read it once converted, but I found the right spot in Parallels to select it nonetheless, just now.

Comment: Post your "fix" as an answer so you can mark it as "answered."  This will help people in the future that run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Figured out that while using the [Parallels blog instructions](https://www.parallels.com/blogs/run-chrome-os-flex-in-parallels-desktop-for-mac/), specifically opening the Chrome OS Flex.pvm linked there, you get a VM in Parallels ready for the ChromeOS Flex USB drive - but, you have to change Boot Order in its config - make sure External device is selected, and pick your USB drive from the External boot device dropdown.

Even when correctly created, the ChromeOS Flex USB drive just doesn't show up in macOS Finder and cannot be selected in a menu as a drive or image.. it does, however, show an EFI drive and USB drive on Win10, but that's all irrelevant since it is selectable for this case in Parallels Boot Order for the provided PVM.

[image]